# gson malformed json exception

Tags: java, json, gson

I am gson to convert my string to jsonObject.
Below is the code snippet

```java
String s = "{orig=2334/342}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
SamplePojo jsn=gson.fromJson(s,SamplePojo.class);
```

But I am getting Below Malformed Json Exception.

It is working fine if I remove `\` from the string.
How to make this one to work with `\` character

I tried with enabling lenient, But it is not working.

```java
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(result1));
reader.setLenient(true);
```

Comment: If you need to convert from the format listed in your question, then you are converting not from JSON but from CLOWN_ON.  Gson does not understand CLOWN_ON.  If you want and/or need to use gson to convert from your input, then you will need to convert from CLOWN_ON to JSON before passing the string to gson.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple issues with your JSON string.

Firstly, JSON uses `:` instead of `=`. Your string `"{orig=2334/342}"` should look more like `"{orig: 2334/342}"`.

Secondly, using an expression as a JSON value can be a bit tricky. If you're using a string, wrap the `2334/342` in single or double quotes like so: `"{orig: '2334/342'}"`.

Try changing the string you're attempting to parse to the following: `"{orig: '2334/342'}"`.

Comment: Yes I agree with json format, But above is my string format that i need to convert.

Comment: @RajeshKumar this isn't an issue with GSON, then, it's an issue with the string you're inputting. GSON parses JSON data, not whatever format you'd like it to parse. If you'd like to use GSON, you must feed it a JSON-formatted string. Why can't you change the string you use?

Comment: @RajeshKumar Why do you think Gson can be used in your case? It is a JSON tool and it obviously cannot be used for strings like you provided (moreover, no JSON tool can do that.) Either fix your JSON-like documents to conform the JSON syntax, or implement your own tool that could work with such strings (whatever that format is).

Comment: @colinrobertson Despite your answer is correct, but such kind of answers are better when posted as comments to the question (since it explains easy trivial things). I'm upvoting it however, because I cannot see any reason of why it was downvoted.

Comment: @fluffy thank you for the upvote! I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but I'm almost there.